# Find number of positive integral solutions of

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find number of positive integral solutions of
$x^4-y^4=30108012$

> How to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a quick answer.

Note that $x^4-y^4 = (x^2+y^2)(x+y)(x-y)$. Each of these terms is odd, or each is even. Because $30108012$ is even, each of these terms is even. Hence, $x^4-y^4$ is divisible by $8$. But  $30108012$ is not divisible by $8$. Thus, there are no solutions.

---

**Edit:** As *tensor* rightly points out, if $x^4-y^4$ is even, it has to be divisible not only by $8$, but also by $16$.

Answer (score 3):

Try factoring both the left and right hand side.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, $x,y$ either both odd or both even... if both are even then $16$ divides the LHS while it doesn't RHS.. If both are odd then $x^4$or  $y^4\equiv 1(\bmod 16)$ ... yielding 
$16\mid (x^4-y^4)$ So, again no solution!!!